# Find infinitely many n such that $\sigma (n) \le \sigma (n+1)$.

Tags: number-theory

I have been stuck on a number theory homework question for some days. It is to Find infinitely many n such that $\sigma (n) \le \sigma (n+1)$. There is a pattern of if $n \gt 2$ then it is true. I thought it had something to do with primes but when 9 and 8 were tried, they worked. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about primes.  In fact, that inequality can be made strict.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then $\sigma(n)=n+1< \sigma(n+1)=n+1+\text{other factors of $n+1$}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is prime then $\sigma(p) = p +1$.
 But $p$ is odd, hence $p+1$ is even so $\sigma(p+1) = 1 + 2 + p+1 + \frac{p+1}{2}+ ...> \sigma(p)$

and the primes are infinite. Also you can prove if $p$ is prime then $\sigma(p) < \sigma(p-1)$